# Can a race condition occur between mutex unlocking and returning from function

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I've been learning about Multithreaded applications and in particular, about how a mutex can be used to prevent race conditions. However, while writing some code, I discovered a race condition (using the `helgrind` tool from `valgrind`) in my code, I believe that execution in one thread may be pausing after the unlock and before the return.

If we take the example code below, **is a race condition possible in between the mutex unlock and the return statement? If so, how do we get around this   problem?** (short of requiring the caller to pass in some sort of buffer and returning a constant value like `0`)

```
#include <pthread.h>

int x = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

doSomething()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    ++x;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
               /* <-- Race Condition? */
    return x;
}

void *t2()
{
    doSomething();
}

main()
{
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_t_create(&thread, NULL);
    doSomething();
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:** I understand that in the above example, returning 'x' is useless, as x is global. However, in a library where 'x' needs to be global for library functions, but can't be exposed to the user, the return  value becomes important.

Comment: Copy x to a local variable inside the lock and then return that copy instead.

Comment: Sidenote: `return` is a statement, not a function. Don't use parentheses around the expression. That can result in subtle errors.

Comment: @Fredrik so then the answer to part 1 of the question (is a race condition possible in between the unlock and return) is yes?

Comment: That's correct a race condition is possible.

Comment: @Fredrik feel free to make your two comments an answer and I'll accept :) Thank You

Comment: Commenting from my phone, to much of a hassle to create an answer ;) thanks for the thought

Comment: @Fredrik why does making a local variable work, exactly?

Comment: @c650 I think it works because each thread has it's own stack, and therefore it's own copy of the local variable. Therefore even if thread 1 has it's execution paused before the return statement, the value of the variable it returns can not be changed by another thread.

Comment: @c650 Because the local variable can't be changed before returned. The variable x could be changed by another thread before returned.

Comment: @Ankush exactly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the sequence of events in your current code:

1. Unlock the lock.
2. Read the shared `x` variable.
3. Return the value you read.

The read of `x` is completely unprotected.

What you need to do is

1. Read the shared `x` variable.
2. Unlock the lock.
3. Return the value you read.

so that the read is protected by the lock. To do that, store the value of `x` to an unshared (local) variable before unlocking the lock, and use that as the return value:

```
int retval = x;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
return retval;
```